# Still the "error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token"

Tags: c, macos, gcc

This is a small pure C program illustrative of the problem. The program doesn't do anything; it's a stripped-down version of a larger program that exhibits the same problem.

Here is the scenario:

Mac OS X Lion;

gcc version i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00);

Sample code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char huge *pbA;
char huge *pbB;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    pbA = (char huge *)farmalloc(2);
    pbB = pbA;
    *(pbB++) = 'A';
    return( 0 );
}
```

Compile command:

```
gcc -c -Wall -O -g -pipe  -D_SDL myTest.c
```

Errors messages:

```
myTest.c:4: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
myTest.c:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
myTest.c: In function ‘main’:
myTest.c:10: error: ‘pbA’ undeclared (first use in this function)
myTest.c:10: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
myTest.c:10: error: for each function it appears in.)
myTest.c:10: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘huge’
myTest.c:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘farmalloc’
myTest.c:11: error: ‘pbB’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

So, what am I missing?

Comment: Looks like `huge` isn't being recognized as anything (I have no idea where it came from). Maybe you forgot a header, possibly the same one containing `farmalloc`?

Comment: Found something on the `huge`: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/911182-can-anybody-explain-following-declaration-i-do-not-understand. Looks like it's deprecated as badly as `far` is. I can only assume `farmalloc` is just as unnecessary. If this is the case, killing the `huge`s and using normal `malloc` should do you well.

Comment: @chris: You should post this as an answer (before I do!).

Comment: @KeithThompson, If you have something to add, please do. I've never heard of either, and searching for *huge in C* to get that specific one doesn't produce many results, even with a couple better-focused keywords.

Comment: @chris: You've covered it as well as I could have.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think your pointers (no pun intended) took me in the right direction. Let me experiment with all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what/where `huge` is, but the compiler can't find it in what you've given it (i.e. you're missing a header probably). As for `farmalloc`, that looks to be in `<alloc.h>`. Now about *using* these, there is an answer on [another site](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/911182-can-anybody-explain-following-declaration-i-do-not-understand) for `huge`:

```
Keywords like near/far/huge were once used as memory models in the old MSDOS 
days when computers had a max of 640K memory.

Any machine built in the last 15 years does not have that restriction so 
unless you have a real issue where you have to use really obsolete hardware, 
I would not spend time with segmented memory model syntax.
```

`huge`, and probably `farmalloc` as well, seem to be deprecated by today's standards (just like far vs near pointers). Using just `char *` and `malloc` should be all you need; no strange, old headers.

Comment: This smells like old 16-bit DOS code being ported into a new environment.

Comment: Yes, it's the "ole DOS code" being ported. Let me experiment with all these great ideas.