# Passing 2dimemnsional array to the function in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

How to pass the 2d array to function I have created one and wanted to define function which initialize this array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int n = 5;**strong text**
void wypelnijTabliceBooli(bool** b){
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            b[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
int main(){
    bool b[n][n];
    wypelnijTabliceBooli(b);
    return 0;
}
```

and i get

```
error: cannot convert 'bool (*)[(((unsigned int)(((int)n) + -0x000000001)) + 1)][(((unsigned int)(((int)n) + -0x000000001)) + 1)]' to 'bool**' for argument '1' to 'void wypelnijTabliceBooli(bool**)'|
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: `bool[n][n]` is not the same as `bool**`. Cannot help more unless you post **real code**.

Comment: @Aiias That's not legal code either.

Comment: @john this is a real code

Comment: @RobertKilar It is now that you have edited it, before `n` was undeclared. That was crucial.

Comment: bool b[n][n]; - that won't work

Comment: @RobertKilar Unfortunately you have chosen to use non-standard C++. `int n = 5; bool b[n][n];` is not legal C++ even before you try to pass the array to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays aren't pointers. Only the "first" (dominant) dimension of an array can **decay into a pointer** when passed to a function. Otherwise, if you have a multidimensional array, you have to declare it in the function argument list accordingly:

```
void funcTaking2DArray(int (*arr)[5])
{
    // do stuff
}

int array[10][5];
funcTaking2DArray(array);
```

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, didn't know about this terminology. Anyways, that's "first", and not "last".

Comment: +1 nice answer =) yeah, its the dimension with all the gusto, as it is the magnitude order for all others that follow *combined*.

Answer (score 1):

Use dimensions:

```
void wypelnijTabliceBooli(bool b[n][n])
```

You could pass it as a pointer to array, but all but the "outermost" dimension needs to be known:

```
void wypelnijTabliceBooli(bool (* b)[n])
```

Edit: I accept that this, with everything else unmodified, requires the GNU or other compilers that have extensions above C++ standard. The alternative is to make `n` a const value.

Comment: Actually, all outer dimensions need to be known, only the first one can be omitted.

Comment: I wonder if this is another gcc extension, or C99?

Comment: @john, GCC has VLAs, yes, but not wit good compiler options turned on.

Comment: @chris no kidding? I thought that feature was *never* going to be in C++. Why would they put it in? How odd.

Comment: @WhozCraig, There's a proposal for it, actually.

Comment: @chris I swear one way or another `_alloca()` will continue to haunt us. You're pretty young so you may not have had the pleasure of that little fiasco.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I can't say I have, but I'll enjoy reading about it. The oldest thing I've had to deal with directly was figuring [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622115/still-the-error-expected-asm-or-attribute-before-to) out.

Comment: @chris thats *awesome*. 20-bit linear addresses formed via 16-bit selector << 4 | 16-bit address. Good times. By the time 286-protected mode came along it was utter salvation for us.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Well, I guess I have learned a bit from my wanderings around Windows, including 16-bit Windows. It's hard not to stumble upon things when they typedef `char *` as `LPSTR` (I'm sure you can guess what it stands for), but there are a lot of things that work so differently from now. Raymond Chen does a good job of that when it's related to Windows.

Comment: @chris I know he's done it a long time. I like reading his old new thing blog regularly. Just imagine back in the day when your DLL was *the* only copy in all of system RAM, the application concurrency was mind-bending. Like I said. good times. (and Long Pointer to String =P, not a guess, used at least a million times in my career)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the size of the array to be flexible. You can declare b as:

```
bool** b = new bool*[n]
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    b[i] = new bool[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know when you use:

```
void wypelnijTabliceBooli(bool** b){
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        b[i][j] = 0;
}
}
```

you can't use indexes do address the bool two dimensional array. This happens because bi-dimensional arrays are stored in contiguous memory places and if you don't provide at least one of the array dimensions there is no way of knowing when does knowing when a given "line ends". example: 
Imagine you have a bool array:

```
bool myArray[2][3]={{true,true,false},{false,false,true}};
```

In memory this will be like that (where [] represents a memory block):

[true][true][false][false][false][true]

and by passing only a pointer to it now you have no way of knowing if this was array[3][2] or array[2][3].

This is solved by passing to the function all but one dimension of the array, like this:

```
void wypelnijTabliceBool(bool b[][3] ){
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        b[i][j] = 0;
}
}
```

(if your second dimension was 3).